# How can I call a particular base class method in Python?

Tags: python

Let's say, I have the following two classes:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, j):
        self.j = j

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        super(C, self).__init__(self, 4)
c = C()
```

c will only have the i attribute set, not the j.
What should I write to set both of attributes/only the j attribute?

Comment: Im guessing B would have to inherit from A and call super aswell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to set only the `j` attribute, then only call `B.__init__`:

```
class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        B.__init__(self,4)
```

If you want to manually call both `A` and `B`'s `__init__` methods, then
of course you could do this:

```
class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self,4)
        B.__init__(self,4)
```

Using `super` is [a bit tricky](http://fuhm.org/super-harmful/) (in particular, see the section entitled "Argument passing, argh!"). If you still want to use `super`, here is one way you could do it:

```
class D(object):
    def __init__(self, i):
        pass
class A(D):
    def __init__(self, i):
        super(A,self).__init__(i)
        self.i = i
class B(D):
    def __init__(self, j):
        super(B,self).__init__(j)        
        self.j = j

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        super(C, self).__init__(4)
c = C()
print(c.i,c.j)
# (4, 4)
```